# Gridview RowCommand does not fire on second time

Tags: asp.net, gridview, response.write, asplinkbutton, rowcommand

i have a gridview and a simple linkbutton with rowcommand like below:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnbTest" CommandName="Download" 
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UPLOADID") %>' Text="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

This linkbutton is for downloading file. I get the UPLOADID and write with Response.WriteFile() method.

THE PROBLEM is when i click on the linkbutton first time, file is downloading but isnt downloading on the second time. Linkbutton does not fire anything. I have searched a lot but couldnt any workaround. It is said it would be related with validation. I have some custom and required validators on my page.

Could anyone suggest me a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any validation control on form?

Comment: yes, I have some custom and required validators on my page

Comment: check the validation causing the firing of rowcommand. if it is the cause then take validation in group.

Comment: What do you mean? my validators are not related with the gridview. There are some another controls and functionality on my page, and the validators are for them. I couldn't understand where to check :S